# Determine whether tab was refreshed intentionally or due to iOS memory constraints

Tags: javascript, web-applications, mobile-safari, local-storage

Mobile Safari and other iOS web browsers (e.g. Chrome) sometimes remove tabs from memory in order to make room for new tabs. This causes the tab to refresh upon regaining focus. The *web application* I'm developing depends heavily upon JS-rendered content and I'd like to be able to restore that content if the page gets removed from memory. I'm already able to do this using the localStorage model. However, I *don't* want to restore the content if the user refreshes the page on purpose (by clicking the Refresh button). Is there a way to differentiate between the two actions, from JavaScript or otherwise?

Comment: Is this an iOS app that you're developing?  Your question is a little vague.

Comment: @iWasRobbed: no, it's a web app intended for mobile devices. Sorry for my vague wording.